# searching a specific position in a field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a ID field that is 11 chars long 123456789abc

1. How can I check the length
2. how can I check position 3 to ensure it's numeric

Select * from table 
where ID = position 2 must be 'A-Z'

Comment: Which rdbms is this?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Comment: SQL Server 2014 Management Studio is not a database management system, or server. That's just the client tool which you use to _connect_ to the database server and interact with it. However it does at least tell us you're using Microsoft SQL Server (since it can only connect to that particular DMBS). Run the query `SELECT @@version` when connected to your server, to know exactly what server version you have.

Comment: To answer the second question, there are two steps: 1) google "sql server find 3rd character in string". 2) google "sql server check if character is numeric". Once you've found those things out, and got a working example of each, try and put it together to form a single query which achieves your overall goal. If you get stuck on _that_, it might be a better time to ask us a question about it. Remember that you are rarely the first person to have a specific problem or requirement, especially fairly small ones like these.

Comment: P.S. To give you some credit, you have at least started to break the overall problem down into separate steps, which is the first thing you always need to do in order to implement something - each individual step is always easier to solve on its own. You just haven't done the next step yet, which is basic research into those individual steps.

Comment: I appreciate all you help, will take all the advice you given for future questions.   I apologize if I wasted anyone time.   Sincerely - Douglas

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you want your query to return. Are you only wanting good rows, ie rows that are 11 characters long and the third character is a number? Or are you wanting to find the "bad" rows that are either not 11 characters long or the third character is not numeric?

Comment: Hi Kevin,   I want to find all ID's where a specific position '3' does not contain A-Z character

Comment: so if I have id's on the table that are 1234567890a, and 12A4567890a   Only the second ID would be picked up because the 3 char is A-Z

Answer (score 1):

You can use `like` with patterns.  Something like this:

```
Select *
from table
where id like '___[0-9]%' and len(id) = @length
```

Comment: Thank you so much,   What part of the query can I specify a specific position in ID.   like the 2nd position of id must equal 0-9

Comment: SELECT [PatientID]
  FROM TABLE
  Where PatientID like '1[1-9]%'   AND
  PatientID LIKE '2[A-Z,^SLOIBZ]%' AND
  PatientID LIKE '3[0-9A-Z^SLOIBZ]%' AND
  PatientID LIKE '4[0-9]%'   AND
  PatientID like '5[A-Z^SLOIBZ]%'  AND
  PatientID like '6[0-9A-Z^SLOIBZ]%' AND
  PatientID like '7[0-9]%'   AND
  PatientID like '8[A-Z^SLOIBZ]%'  AND
  PatientID like '9[A-Z^SLOIBZ]%'  AND
  PatientID like '10[0-9]%'   AND
  PatientID like '11[0-9]%'